# UITabBar tintColor is not changed storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have set a global tintColor, and I can see it in  the interface builder, when I select UITabBar as well as UITabBarController, still when I run the application, the tint of the selected UITabBarItem is iOS default (blue), and not what I have set. What am I missing?

P.S. 
UITabBarController is pushed to navigationController, it is not the rootViewController

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your `appDelegate`

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```

Replace red color with color you want.

Comment: in iOS setSelectedImageTintColor deprecated, tintColor should be used instead. Swift version:         
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red

Comment: Could someone update this answer to reflect the API changes in newer iOS releases? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Storyboard doesn't support that directly yet. But you can set an **user defined runtime attribute** in storyboard.

Select the tab bar of the tab bar controller.
[image: Select the tab bar of the tab bar controller.]

Select the identity inspector. (The view where you can set the class of a view.)

[image: Select the identity inspector]

And if you want to **change the selected item's tint color** instead, just use the `selectedImageTintColor` Key Path instead.

Comment: It is good solution but I am not sure why it does not work on iOS 10. The code solution by Scott work fine

Comment: Solution by Scott work but it has another problem which it changes tintColor of tabbar (all items on tabbar) not one tab!

Comment: This is the real winner. Just combine what we know from both answers: set the key path as 'selectedImageTintColor' instead of 'tintColor' and voila -> no code required.

Comment: tintColor is not working and also selectImageTintColor is depreciated now (Swift 3.0)

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting iOS 8 then

> selectedImageTintColor is deprecated in iOS 8 use tintColor

Swift

```
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Objective c

```
   [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I put the same code in appDelegate but not working although unselectedItemTintColor is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I wanted each ViewController to have a unique TabBarItem color when presented.

[image]

In iOS 8, the manual addition of a tintColor attribute in the storyboard worked fine, but no longer has any effect under iOS 9 / Xcode 8.

I solved the problem by including the following code in each of my TabBarController's children ViewControllers, overriding each of their ViewDidAppear() functions.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whateverColor
    //The rest of your code
}
```

This is safe in any ViewController, due to the ? after the tabBarController call.  If the ViewController is not embedded in a TabBarController, the entire line is simply ignored.

By placing this code in each of your VCs, you can specify the color of each TabBarItem easily.